# How to construct fermi surface of an electron moving in a 1d periodic lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

For free electron the fermi surface is a sphere. Now let  the electron moves through a one dimensional lattice consisting of positive ion chores that are placed in a periodic arrangement. How to construct the fermi surface for this system in an analytical method?

Comment: In the weak potential approximation you can use perturbation theory to find the dispersion relation. With that you easily find the analytic form of the Fermi surface.

Comment: The Fermi surface is a sphere only in 3d, when the wave vector has three components.